# Extending several lists elegantly

Tags: python, list

Given several lists:

```
a = ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
b = ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
...
n = ["n1", "n2", "n3"]
```

And a list of new values:

```
new_vals = ["a4", "b4", "n4"]
```

I would like to get:

```
["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"]
["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"]
...
["n1", "n2", "n3", "n4"]
```

I can do this with loops and temporary variables, of course. It seems like come combination of `zip`, `map`, and `list.extend` should do it more elegantly, but is eluding me.

Comment: Does this mean you have 14 lists and 3 new values?  How are you matching the new values and the original lists?  Do the values always start with the variable name for the list?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
a = ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
b = ["b1", "b2", "b3"]

# Put the list a, b ... in a big_list. 
big_list = [a, b]

new_vals = ["a4", "b4", "n4"]

for i, new_val in enumerate(new_vals):
    big_list[i].append(new_val)
```

Comment: Even more pythonic: 1st line: `for big_sublist, new_val in zip(big_list, new_vals):` and 2nd line: `big_sublist.append(new_val)`

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a list of lists:

```
lsts = [ ['a1','a2','a3'],
         ['b1','b2','b3'],
         ['c1','c2','c3'] ]
```

and a list that you of new values that you want to append to the end of each list in `lsts`:

```
lst = [ 'a4', 'b4', 'c4' ]
```

Then you can use a list comprehension:

```
new_lsts = [l + [x] for l, x in zip(lsts, lst)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A map() oriented solution:

```
a = ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
b = ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
n = ["n1", "n2", "n3"]
new_vals = ["a4", "b4", "n4"]

map(lambda lst, x: lst.append(x), (a, b, n), new_vals)
```

And incorporating the list of lists suggestions above:

```
lsts = [['a1','a2','a3'],
        ['b1','b2','b3'],
        ['c1','c2','c3']]
new_vals = ["a4", "b4", "c4"]
map(lambda lst, x: lst.append(x), lsts, new_vals)
```

This might be preferable since it modifies lsts in-place instead of creating a new list of lists.

Comment: nice indeed, +1. What can be surprising at first is that one just have to ignore the result of the map, because append returns None.